# Cannot create timer in LuaNode

Tags: lua, iot, esp32

I am using the DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1 (www.doit.com) development board.

[LuaNode](https://github.com/Nicholas3388/LuaNode) is loaded. When the device is reset, version 1.3.0 is reported

```
=======================================
LuaNode: https://github.com/Nicholas3388/LuaNode
Version: 1.3.0
=======================================
```

lib `tmr` is also loaded.

Trying to use a simple timer fails:

```
> t = tmr.create()
stdin:1: attempt to call field 'create' (a nil value)
```

Comment: What is lib `tmr` and how it was loaded? Looks like it haven't been  loaded properly.

Comment: @ephemerr https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/tmr/ The log states it is loaded, found no error messages

Comment: There is timer example on LuaNode project's site. Does it work? If not try to rise issue there  https://github.com/Nicholas3388/LuaNode/blob/master/LuaNode_Esp32/LuaNode32/lua_samples/timer/timer.lua

Comment: @ephemerr Yes, the basic examples work. But scheduling (register) and the method described in this post do not work